# converting CLOB to JAVA object

Tags: json, clob

I have stored my data in CLOB as a JSON format. And i would like to retrieve the clob content and convert it to a JAVA Object. How can i do that first.
I cannot convert CLOB content to string, since am converting the string in java object to JSON format(@produces ("application/json")) as my return type in webservice endpoint..

Comment: I did this by using gson.jar. It converts json to java object and java object to json